# .NET Isolated Storage

Tags: .net, vb.net, isolatedstorage, isolatedstoragefile

I am going through a Windows application trying to find ways to speed things up. One item I've noticed is the datasets which are retrieved from the database are then written to `System.IO.IsolatedStorage.IsolatedStorageFile`.

After reading a bit about the Isolated Storage uses, I feel like the application is not using it correctly, as it is not intended for large data sets (5K plus). Commenting out the 'IsolatedStorageFile caching' the application's performance was visibly improved. But I am concerned I am not fully understanding storage functionality to blindly comment it out.

Can't seem to find much about it online, with good examples. Would anyone be willing to explain what the Isolated Storage files are intended to be used for? is it just for smaller settings type things?

Comment: Does [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.isolatedstorage?view=net-7.0) not answer your question?

Comment: @djv i've been reading all the Microsoft help files. trying to figure out if keeping large datasets retrieved from the database is hurting performance instead of benefiting. From what i can tell removing isolated storage (and just read data directly from database) is improving the speed, but i want to make sure i won't break something

Comment: `With these stores, you can read and write data that less trusted code cannot access and prevent the exposure of sensitive information that can be saved elsewhere on the file system` if you aren't interested in keeping sensitive information hidden outside of your code, then you don't need to use it. If that's required, then the time it takes to store / retrieve it is secondary.

Comment: @djv  i understand thank you, but if i am reading a dataset from the database and using it in the code right away, without having to save it to disk, is that less secure then reading from database, then saving to/retrieving from isolated storage, and then using it? i do not have the need to save any files to the drive. so I guess i'm just trying to understand if what we are currently doign with isolated storage is redundant. (grab from db -> save to isolated storage -> read from isolated storage->use to populate a grid)

Comment: It sounds like you may not need to store to the local disk. The isolated storage shouldn't be available outside of your application but local storage is useful in many scenarios such as when your database may not be available, or storing settings you want to reload into your application upon the next launch without hitting the database. Maybe the `we` in your last comment is the key here, as I guess there is some knowledge somebody has elsewhere in your collective `we`, which nobody else on SO would ever have. Ask around if you can...

Comment: thank you! nobody seems to know anything, and the people who wrote the application are long gone. i appreciate your help! i will try to remove it and test performance again.  thank you again.